# How to change the direction of cometchat

Tags: css

i have integrated a cometchat in my website. But i want to move the cometchat bar from footer to right-side.

(the default cometchat bar is in the footer just like fb chat).

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: **Is there anyway to do this?** Yes, there is. How? We'll need some code, or markup to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Jo_zhu, welcome to the community, Can you please provide your code/screenshot/ fiddle. so we can see the issues where you are lagging. You can put your code on http://jsfiddle.net and paste the link.

Answer (score 2):

- Login to Cometchat Administration panel.
- Click on Setting tab.
- Under setting tab change 'Bar layout' to 'Fixed'.
- Select 'Right' in 'If set to fixed, enter alignment of the bar'

This will make the bar aligned to right.

You can also make 'Padding of bar from the end of the window' to '0' so it will stick to right side window.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to switch to light weight mode and you will get a facebook line panel to the right This can be done from cometchat admin panel